# Init git repo on remote server set up for ssh

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have a server where I wish to store git repositories as remote. I have set up ssh access using key pairs. I have also created an entry in the .ssh/config file just to keep things simple. I would like to avoid ssh-ing over to the server every time I create a repo and I'd like to be able to do: `git init --bare myServer:/home/my-git-user/my-repo.git` from my workstation.

Unfortunately this creates a folder called 'myServer:/home..blah...' in the current working directory.

Is there any way to make git init interpret that argument as a remote location? When I set up a remote with:

`git remote add myRemote myServer:/home/my-git-user/my-repo.git`

it figures it out obviously. So I guess what I want is not impossible.

Edit: the reason I find this especially annoying is that the user managing the git on that server does not even have proper shell access (as per git tutorial on setting up a server). So I can't even ssh in to set up the repo, I would need to ssh in as someone else (root) then set up the repo, THEN fix ownership on the repo. So the one command to set up the repo became three...

Comment: You can't remotely create a repo on another host _with git alone_. If you find it's too cumbersome, create a script for it: `init-remote-repo myServer home/my-git-user/my-repo.git`

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about it, but then this script has to be _somewhere_ and I have to manage it. I thought git _is_ that script. :) Then maybe giving the user shell access is easier. It's only for home anyway.

Comment: You can overkill it by setting up a web app on the server so that you can _hit it_ and it will take care of creating the repo.

Comment: Git is intended to work only with the local repository. There're very few commands that query/exchange data with distant (I don't use the word "remote" here to avoid confusion with locally stored URLs) repositories: `archive`, `clone`, `fetch`, `ls-remote`, `pull`, `push`, `remote` are the only ones I know. Certainly not `git init`.

Comment: Ah yes, let's overkill it! :D I write an API in java using Spring to create the repo. Then I design a PCB with an ESP32 and a button for it. AND a phone app in Flutter. I have a feeling that people would just love it on instructables.

Comment: If the user doesn't have shell access with what magic do you expect `git init myServer:/path` would work (even if it could)? Git has to run some commands on the server side. No shell access — no commands.

Comment: @phd ok, not no shell, it's set to use the git-shell.

Comment: With the help of another ssh route (with sudo) to the server ```ssh myServer 'sudo -u gitUser git init --bare /home/gitUser/myRepo.git'``` does the trick.

Comment: [`git shell`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) allows custom commands so if you could configure them you could avoid `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eftshift0 and @phd pointed out it is not going to happen with `git init` only as it was not designed to to that. With sufficient ssh access however it can be reduced to a single command:

`ssh <server> 'sudo -u my-git-user git init --bare /home/my-git-user/my-repo.git'`

where `<server>` is obviously something like `ssh-user@my-ip` depending on the setup (with port, key, whatever...)

Or a shell script can to most of the typing i.e. initGitRepo.sh:

`ssh my-user@my-ip "sudo -u git-user git init --bare /home/git-user/$1.git"`

Then after making it executable use it as: `initGitRepo.sh my-repo`